# Poner un LocalDate en null dentro constructor sin error

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de clase donde tengo que crear un constructor y meter datos con arboles etc, el caso es que un campo que es fecha de baja hay empleados que no tienen debería a ponerlo en nulo cosa que en el constructor no me deja ponerlo(No encuentro la manera).
Os dejo aquí un ejemplo de un empleado:

```
Empleado empleado1 =new Empleado("Pepe",Categoria.EMPLEADO, LocalDate.of(2011,3,21), LocalDate.of(2013, 4,22));
```

y Aqui el constructor:

```
Empleado(String nombre, Categoria categoria, LocalDate fechaAlta, LocalDate fechaBaja) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    FechaAlta = fechaAlta;
    FechaBaja = fechaBaja;
    clave=asignarClave(categoria);
}
```

Comment: ¿el constructor no te deja hacer `new Empleado("Pepe", Categoria.EMPLEADO, LocalDate.of(2011,3,21), null)`?

Comment: debería estar bien de esa manera pero algo tengo mal que me marca fallo antes de compilar incluso

Comment: ¿Por qué no implementas [*constructores encadenados*](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-constructor-chaining-with-example/)  para este caso? Por ejemplo, tendrías un constructor: `Empleado(String nombre, Categoria categoria, LocalDate fechaAlta) {`, así, para los nuevos empleados o los que no tengan fecha de baja, le pasas solamente esos tres parámetros. También puedes tener tu constructor actual: `Empleado(String nombre, Categoria categoria, LocalDate fechaAlta, LocalDate fechaBaja) {`, el cual sólo usarás cuando conozcas la fecha de baja al momento de crear el objeto.

Comment: poné el mensaje de error.

Comment: Si quieres ayuda, deberías poner la información relevante del problema (como por ejemplo, el mensaje de error que sería **el mínimo absoluto**, o el hecho de que tienes definidos otros constructores). Mira [mcve].

Comment: La proxima vez, intentare formular mejor mi pregunta, lo solucione con los dos constructores, muchisimas gracias a  todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este tipo de casos en Java se resuelve con lo que se conoce como [*Sobrecarga de Constructores*](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/constructor-overloading/).

En una clase puedes tener varios constructores (uno vacío, que toda clase tiene por defecto) y puedes tener varios constructores que acepten `N` cantidad de parámetros. Según el contexto en que vayas a crear la instancia del objeto, usarás el constructor adecuado según los datos de que dispongas al momento de crear la instancia, evitando así el trasiego de valores nulos.

Para el caso que expones, puedes tener un constructor que incluya `fechaBaja`, el cual usarás cuando conozcas ese dato. Y tendrás un constructor sin `fechaBaja`, que usarás cuando no conozcas ese dato.

```
class Empleado
{
   private String name;
   private String category;
   private LocalDate beginDate;
   private LocalDate endDate;

   public Empleado()
   {
       //constructor por defecto
   }

   //Se usará cuando conozcas la fechaFinal
   public Empleado(String name, String category, LocalDate beginDate, LocalDate endDate)
   {
       //asignación de valores
   }

   //Se usará cuando NO conozcas la fechaFinal
   public Empleado(String name, String category, LocalDate beginDate)
   {
       //asignación de valores
   }

   // ...

}
```